# ie6 - gd and php image outputting

Tags: php, image, internet-explorer-6, gd

i'm trying to show image with grayscale-filter. Here is my code:

```
$images = glob('gallery/*small*');
shuffle($images);
array_splice($images, 3);

$imgHandles = array();
$imgBuffered = array();
for( $i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)
{  
   $imgHandles[$i] = imagecreatefromstring( file_get_contents($images[$i]) ); 
   imagefilter( $imgHandles[$i], IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE ); 

   ob_start();
   imagepng( $imgHandles[$i] ); 
   $imgBuffered[$i] = ob_get_contents();
   ob_end_clean();
   imagedestroy( $imgHandles[$i] ); 
}
```

And outputting:

```
for( $i = 0; $i < 3; $i++ )
{  
   echo "<a href=\"gallery.php\">
   <img class=\"photo\" src='data:image/png;base64,".base64_encode( $imgBuffered[$i] )."' /></a>";                                                                                    
}
```

### In opera, ff, chrome, safari everything is fine, but ie6 doesn't show images. Why?

I made code like at page: http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2005/06/base64-ie/
I see pictures, but in some seconds they hide... I really don't know why. Can you help me with this stuff?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data URI scheme [isn't supported in IE6 (nor IE7, apparently)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). You'll need to save the image somewhere and provide the URL to the saved image as the `img src`, or you'll need to generate it on the fly via a separate script and do something like `img src="path/to/image_generator.php"`.

Comment: content of image generator script is that, what i have in my page now? Could you show an example, please?

Comment: Request-URI Too Large - my images are too big for passing them into url-query.

Comment: Yes, it would be silly to pass the image data to the image generator via a query string. You'd want to pass the image generator a unique identifier that lets you find the image - something like its filename, `$i` from your script, etc.

Answer (score 1):

ceejayoz's approach is probably best, and he\she is correct in saying that the scheme isn't supported in IE6. [Here is a page about how to do it in IE](http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2005/06/base64-ie/), but I hope you have a good reason for not doing the `/path/to/image_generator.php` version.

To do that, you would create a script that just does `imagepng`, for example, and then sends headers indicating to the browser that the image in question is a png. e.g.,

`img_generate.php`:

```
$images = glob('gallery/*small*');

$img_to_generate=intval($_GET['image_to_generate']);



$imgHandle = imagecreatefromstring( file_get_contents($images[$img_to_generate]) ); 
imagefilter( $imgHandle, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE ); 

header('Content-type:image/png');//tell the browser what to expect
imagepng( $imgHandle ); //output the image
imagedestroy( $imgHandles ); //clean up
```

and then in your html

```
<img src="/path/to/img_generate.php?image_to_generate=0" alt="image 0" />
<img src="/path/to/img_generate.php?image_to_generate=1" alt="image 1" />
<img src="/path/to/img_generate.php?image_to_generate=2" alt="image 2" />
```